# Cloud9 - Node.js fs can't open an html file

Tags: html, node.js, fs

I do experiments with **node.js** and socket.io and **it works fine locally.**
I can read an html file and manage an interactive button for several users.

So i uploaded it on **Cloud9** but i have an **error ENOENT trying to find the html file**. 
It's in root (like in local) and the line is fs.readFile('ex.html' etc...

Here is the code of a **test** to open an html file and i have the **enoent error** on the console :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('ex.html', function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            response.end(data);
        });
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

---

Here is **another program (full)** that displays a **blank page**...

*server :*

```
var http    =    require('http');
var fs      =   require('fs');

// Creation du serveur
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // On lit notre fichier app.html
    fs.readFile('app.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

var io = require("socket.io");
io = io.listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('joue', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('joue2');

  }); // joue


});  // connection


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

---

*client (app.html) :*

```
<html><head> <title>Hello</title></head><body>


<button id="button">clic</button>
<div id="render">a</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var socket = io.connect();
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var render = document.getElementById('render');
button.addEventListener("click", clique, false);



       function clique() {
       socket.emit('joue');
        }

         socket.on('joue2', function () {

            if (render.innerHTML == 'a') {
                render.innerHTML = 'clic multi';
            } else {
                render.innerHTML = 'a';
            }

    });

</script></body></html>
```

---

I have installed socket.io on the server and all files are in the root of the folder node.js. 
I already asked to Cloud9 but they said it works for them... 
Sorry for my english and if im a beginner.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `ex.html` file is in node.js directory.

Try `fs.readFile('node.js/ex.html', ...`